# TimescaleDB: force refresh or stability continuous aggregated views in functional testing

Tags: timescaledb

I am using TimescaleDB as a backend for time-series data. Now I am writing some unit and functional tests against this backend.

- I spin up a new database from a PostgreSQL template
- The template has continuos aggregated views set up
- I load up data from test fixtures using bulk `INSERT`, etc.
- Now I want my tests to query against those aggregated views

However, as far as I understand, continuous aggregated views are refreshed on a background by TimescaleDB worker processes. For the test to be correct, I need to be sure that all continuous aggregated views are up-to-date.

Is there a way for me to query TimescaleDB for the updateness of a continuous aggregated view and wait until it has properly ingested all data as the result of INSERTs? Or should any INSERT automatically be reflected in all continuous aggregated views on commit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to using [continuous aggregate policies](https://docs.timescale.com/api/latest/continuous-aggregates/add_continuous_aggregate_policy/), which refreshes continuous aggregates on a schedule, it is possible to manually refresh continuous aggregates on demand by calling [refresh_continuous_aggregate()](https://docs.timescale.com/api/latest/continuous-aggregates/refresh_continuous_aggregate/#required-arguments). It might be also useful to read [this intro](https://docs.timescale.com/timescaledb/latest/overview/core-concepts/continuous-aggregates/#an-introductory-example). Example from the docs:

```sql
CALL refresh_continuous_aggregate('conditions', '2020-01-01', '2020-02-01');
```

A side note, which might be useful to know: you can tweak if the continuous aggregate should returned only materialized aggregates or calculate from hypertable by setting [timescaledb.materialized_only](https://docs.timescale.com/api/latest/continuous-aggregates/alter_materialized_view/#sample-usage) on the view.

Comment: Thank you. `refresh_continuos_aggregate` was exactly what I was looking for.